# Find amount greater than the average amount

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

[enter link description here](https://www.data.gov.uk/dataset/22a8f668-9cf5-43b6-b097-8be0303ad74d/spend-over-25-000-in-the-department-for-business-innovation-and-skills)[image]

I want to show expense types that have a half year spend amount greater than the average half‐year expense type spend for each of the half‐years April‐September and October‐March.

Sample data (associated fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/G6b9TKhB):

| Expense_Type | Amount | Date_Of_Payment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Consultancy Expenditure | 5000.00 | 2022-05-15 |
| Criminal Law | -2500.50 | 2022-08-22 |
| External Training | 7500.75 | 2022-11-10 |
| Consultancy Expenditure | 12000.00 | 2023-01-05 |
| External Training | -5000.25 | 2023-04-18 |
| Criminal Law | 80000.00 | 2023-07-02 |
| Consultancy Expenditure | -3000.50 | 2023-09-14 |
| External Training | 6000.25 | 2023-12-28 |
| Criminal Law | 3500.00 | 2023-02-08 |
| Criminal Law | -10000.00 | 2022-06-30 |
| Consultancy Expenditure | 9500.00 | 2022-04-20 |
| External Training | -7500.75 | 2022-10-05 |
| Criminal Law | 3000.50 | 2022-12-15 |
| Consultancy Expenditure | -18000.00 | 2023-01-25 |
| External Training | 2000.25 | 2023-03-12 |
| Criminal Law | -60000.00 | 2023-05-28 |
| Consultancy Expenditure | 4500.50 | 2023-08-07 |
| External Training | 3000.75 | 2023-10-19 |
| Criminal Law | 12000.00 | 2023-01-02 |
| Criminal Law | -5000.00 | 2022-07-15 |
| Consultancy Expenditure | 6000.00 | 2022-09-28 |
| External Training | -3000.25 | 2023-11-10 |
| Criminal Law | 9000.50 | 2023-04-01 |
| Consultancy Expenditure | -12000.00 | 2023-06-14 |
| External Training | 1500.25 | 2023-09-26 |
| Criminal Law | 5500.00 | 2023-12-09 |
| Consultancy Expenditure | 8000.50 | 2023-02-22 |
| External Training | -4500.75 | 2022-05-03 |
| Criminal Law | 18000.00 | 2022-08-17 |
| Consultancy Expenditure | -3000.00 | 2022-11-30 |
| External Training | 2500.75 | 2023-02-14 |
| Criminal Law | -7500.50 | 2023-05-01 |
| Consultancy Expenditure | 7000.25 | 2023-08-14 |
| External Training | -2000.25 | 2023-10-27 |
| Criminal Law | 4000.00 | 2023-01-09 |
| Consultancy Expenditure | -6000.50 | 2022-07-22 |
| External Training | 3500.75 | 2022-09-04 |
| Criminal Law | 15000.00 | 2023-11-17 |
| Consultancy Expenditure | 2000.50 | 2023-04-05 |
| External Training | -1200.25 | 2023-07-18 |
| Criminal Law | -3000.00 | 2023-09-30 |
| Consultancy Expenditure | 10000.25 | 2023-12-13 |
| External Training | 5000.00 | 2023-02-28 |
| Criminal Law | -4500.50 | 2022-06-13 |
| Consultancy Expenditure | 3000.75 | 2022-10-26 |
| External Training | -2500.75 | 2022-12-08 |
| Criminal Law | 6000.00 | 2023-03-23 |
| Consultancy Expenditure | -1500.00 | 2023-06-06 |
| External Training | 1200.25 | 2023-09-19 |
| Criminal Law | 2500.50 | 2023-12-02 |

I have tried this SQL:

```sql
select 
    avgvalue > average   -- I want to show all expense type greater than average.
from 
    (select 
         sum(Amount) as avgvalue,
         avg(sum(Amount)) as average
     from 
         mydatatable
     where
         (DateofPayment like '%/04/%' or
          DateofPayment like '%/05/%' or 
          DateofPayment like '%/06/%' or 
          DateofPayment like '%/07/%' or
          DateofPayment like '%/08/%' or
          DateofPayment like '%/09/%') 
     group by 
         ExpenseType) z
```

I found avg amount and sum of same expense type. But did not know how to do. please help

I need code to get all expense type in months April to September. First sum all same expense type to make expense type unique. then take average of all sum amount then show all expense type with an amount that is greater than average

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server; what RDBMS are you *really* using? If you are using SQL Server, are you *really* using SQL Server 2008? That version ran *completely* out of support *over **4 years*** ago. It is long past time you implemented your upgrade plan by now.

Comment: Syntax like `DateofPayment like '%/07/%'` has a large smell to it as well, as it implies that your column `DateOfPayment` is a string based data type; a fatal design flaw that *needs* fixing ASAP. Also what is `like '%/07/%'` meant to achieve? Anything from the 7th month of the year?

Comment: yes I get all ExpenseType and amount cloumn from my table where month is 4 to 9 of all year. Then I group ExpenseType to make expenseType column unique. Like 1 have same expensetype more than 1 time. I make expentype unique and add their value. Like if I have 3 expensetype same. I write 1 time and add value of 3

Comment: After that I have column with ExpenseType and Amount. Now I want to take average of amount column. then I want to show expenseType and amount where amount is greater than average amount.

Comment: '%/07/%' by this I get all values containing 4 month ignoring date and year

Comment: @AmmaraRasheed So you want to find the Expense Types whose total amount sum is greater than the average of that total amount sum? My math is rusty, but that seems odd. Or greater than the average of the other total amounts for all Expense Types? Why is the sum(Amount) considered the "avgvalue"? For me, it's not entirely clear what you want.

Comment: select avg(avgvalue) as average
    from 
    (
        select sum(Amount) as avgvalue
        from mydatatable
  WHERE (DateofPayment like '%/04/%' OR  DateofPayment like '%/05/%' OR  DateofPayment like '%/06/%'
  OR  DateofPayment like '%/07/%' OR  DateofPayment like '%/08/%' OR  DateofPayment like '%/09/%') 
        group by ExpenseType
    )z

Comment: @AmmaraRasheed If you added some sample data and result to demonstrate exactly what you are looking for that'd do wonders.

Comment: I send code in comment

Comment: If you run this code, it give me average. Thats fine

Comment: I want to get this. show Expense Types that have a half year spend amount greater than the average half‐year Expense Type spend for each of the half‐ years April‐September and October‐March. I have expense column and amount column.

Comment: my code give me average amount in results like 223233222.2322. I want to show amount> average.

Comment: I tell you again step by step

Comment: You need to provide table definitions (create table statements), sample data as inserts and a clear example of desired output based on the sample data provided. This is so vague at this point and you still haven't even told us which database you are actually using.

Comment: First I get all expenseType and amount where month is April to September. I use %/4/% to ignore date and year. like getting value from april month of all year 2014, 2015 etc

Comment: microsoft sql server managment studio query

Comment: I edit and put image

Comment: please help I am struggling from many days

Comment: Images in general are pretty useless. Why? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors#:~:text=Images%20are%20harder%20to%20read,actual%20code%20and%20formatting%20it. But yours provides zero insight into what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sir I need sql query to get above task. I explain all

Comment: Yes you explained it, although rather vaguely. But what you haven't provided is table definitions and sample data. The things needed for others to be able to run code and test their solution. In a consulting environment I would be thrilled to bill you an hourly rate to generate sample data. But in an online forum you have to do the leg work so the people offering their time for free don't have to work so hard. If you provide sample data and table definitions I will help. Otherwise, good luck.

Comment: @AmmaraRasheed I know it's frustrating when a problem statement that is clear as day to you falls on deaf ears. The guidelines for questions are there for a reason, because they help us help you. Please see this question (tooting my own horn because I can't find a nice example asked from today) for a IMO good example of the content and layout for a question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66498440/pivot-denormalize-over-effective-ranges With the sample data (as text) and a clear expected result I got an excellent answer to a complex problem quickly.

Comment: @AmmaraRasheed So out of the goodness of my heart, and boredom with what I should actually be working on I've generated some digestible sample data for your question and a fiddle. On principle with the datatype of DateOfPayment as a date. If you provide your expected results associated with this sample data as text in a table ... I (or someone else) will promptly answer your question. For what it's worth, ChatGPT is actually a pretty good sample data generator. Just tell it the columns you want and the range of values they are allowed to have.

Comment: That screenshot clearly demonstrates you *are* storing dates as a `varchar`; you ***need*** to fix that.

Comment: *@AmmaraRasheed - Vandalism edits were submitted (and have since been rejected) for this post and at least one of the answers. You account may have been compromised or perhaps you left your login active on a publicly accessible machine.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a window function `AVG(...) OVER ()` to average all values in the table.

```sql
SELECT
 *
FROM (
    SELECT
      ExpenseType,
      SUM(Amount) AS sum,
      AVG(SUM(Amount)) OVER () AS average
    FROM mydatatable
    WHERE DATEPART(month, DateofPayment) BETWEEN 4 AND 9 
    GROUP BY ExpenseType
) z
WHERE avgvalue > average
```

Comment: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. error

Comment: Suggested tweak: Rename `avgvalue` as `sumvalue` or similar.

Comment: also please show how to write query for this.  Show a monthly top 10 ranking for spend on Expense Areas. For 
each Expense area indicate the number of places it has moved 
(up/down the rankings) since the previous month. The ranking must 
be in ascending order.

Comment: `Dateofpayment` should already be a `datetime` why is it a string type? Or convert it in the query. If you have a new problem I suggest you create a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

If this were SQL Server 2022, I would suggest using the `DATE_BUCKET()` function to cleanly map the source dates into 6-month *buckets*.

For earlier versions of SQL server, you can use the following calculation:

```
DATEADD(
    month,
    DATEDIFF(month, '1900-04-01', DateOfPayment ) / 6 * 6,
    '1900-04-01'
    ) AS DateBucket
```

Here, `'1900-04-01'` is reference date used to define the start of some arbitrary 6-month window (bucket). The `/ 6 * 6` is used to round the month number down to the prior 6-month multiple.

This can then be wrapped up in a `CROSS APPLY` and used in later `GROUP BY` or window function `PARTITION BY` conditions.

The resulting query would be something like:

```
select
    DateBucket as FromDate,
    dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(month, 6, DateBucket)) as ThruDate,
    Expense_Type,
    SumAmount,
    AvgSumAmount
from (
    select
        DateBucket,
        Expense_Type,
        sum(Amount) as SumAmount,
        avg(sum(Amount)) OVER(PARTITION BY DateBucket) AS AvgSumAmount
    from ExpenseTable E
    cross apply (
        select dateadd(
            month, 
            datediff(month, '1900-04-01', Date_Of_Payment ) / 6 * 6,
            '1900-04-01'
            ) AS DateBucket
    ) b
    group by DateBucket, Expense_Type
) a
where SumAmount > AvgSumAmount
order by DateBucket, Expense_Type;
```

The inner query calculates the 6-month date bucket and then groups the expense data by date bucket and expense type, summing the amount in the process. It also calculates the average-total-expense for each date bucket using a window function. The top level then just applies the final filter condition for the results.

Results:

| FromDate | ThruDate | Expense_Type | SumAmount | AvgSumAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-01 | 2022-09-30 | Consultancy Expenditure | 14499.50 | 3166.166666 |
| 2022-10-01 | 2023-03-31 | Criminal Law | 28500.50 | 12500.666666 |
| 2023-04-01 | 2023-09-30 | Criminal Law | 18500.00 | 4000.250000 |
| 2023-10-01 | 2024-03-31 | Criminal Law | 23000.50 | 12333.750000 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xn9OVDLZ) or [this one](https://dbfiddle.uk/Lm2IczHb) for a demo.

Comment: DATEADD(
    month,
    DATEDIFF(month, '1900-04-01', DateOfPayment ) / 6 * 6,
    '1900-04-01'
    ) AS DateBucket This gives error due to month.Incorrect syntax near 'month'.

Comment: That was a code snippet. What do you get if you wrap it up in a complete statement like `SELECT DATEADD( month, DATEDIFF(month, '1900-04-01', GetDate() ) / 6 * 6, '1900-04-01' ) AS DateBucket`. I only have the ability to test code back to SQL Server 2014. Even documentation for 2008 is hard to find.